# Java code to replace index with next 4 indexes added together

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to code a way to replace the specific i index of an array with the next 4 indexes.
Ex. if there are 20 arrays spots, array index 0 is equal to index 1+2+3+4 and so forth. When you reach index 17, it does 18+19+20, but I need  the last index to now become index 0, giving 18+19+20+0 = index 17

Heres what I have so far:

```
public static void addNextFour(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i + 1] + a[i + 2] + a[i + 3] + a[i + 4];
            System.out.print(a[i]);
            if (a[i] > a[16]) {
                a[i] = a[i - 20];
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the results of the calculations should be stored in another array so that the sum of the elements at the tail take into original values of the input array `a`:

```java
// code with debug prints
public static void addNextFourPrint(int... a) {
    // print input array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sb.append("a[").append(i).append("] = ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            int k = (i + j) % a.length;
            if (j > 1) {
                sb.append(" + ");
            }
            
            sb.append(a[k]);
            b[i] += a[k];  // b[i] = a[i + 1] + ... + a[i + 4] 
        }
        sb.append(" = ").append(b[i]);
        System.out.println(sb); // print each element
        sb.setLength(0); // clear string builder
    }
    // print result
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));    
}
```

Test

```java
addNextFourPrint(2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 11, 0, 13, 8, 9, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6);
```

Output

```
[2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 11, 0, 13, 8, 9, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6]
a[0] = 5 + 1 + 7 + 3 = 16
a[1] = 1 + 7 + 3 + 9 = 20
a[2] = 7 + 3 + 9 + 6 = 25
a[3] = 3 + 9 + 6 + 9 = 27
a[4] = 9 + 6 + 9 + 4 = 28
a[5] = 6 + 9 + 4 + 8 = 27
a[6] = 9 + 4 + 8 + 11 = 32
a[7] = 4 + 8 + 11 + 0 = 23
a[8] = 8 + 11 + 0 + 13 = 32
a[9] = 11 + 0 + 13 + 8 = 32
a[10] = 0 + 13 + 8 + 9 = 30
a[11] = 13 + 8 + 9 + 1 = 31
a[12] = 8 + 9 + 1 + 7 = 25
a[13] = 9 + 1 + 7 + 5 = 22
a[14] = 1 + 7 + 5 + 2 = 15
a[15] = 7 + 5 + 2 + 6 = 20
a[16] = 5 + 2 + 6 + 2 = 15
a[17] = 2 + 6 + 2 + 5 = 15
a[18] = 6 + 2 + 5 + 1 = 14
a[19] = 2 + 5 + 1 + 7 = 15
[16, 20, 25, 27, 28, 27, 32, 23, 32, 32, 30, 31, 25, 22, 15, 20, 15, 15, 14, 15]
```

---

A version without debug prints may look as follows (returning modified array):

```java
public static int[] addNextFour(int... a) {
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            b[i] += a[(i + j) % a.length];
        }
        System.out.print(b[i] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return b;
}
```

Similarly, it can be implemented using Stream API `IntStream::range + rangeClosed`, `IntStream::map`, `IntStream::peek`, `IntStream::sum`:

```java
public static int[] addNextFourStream(int... a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .map(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(i + 1, i + 4).map(j -> a[j % a.length]).sum())
        .peek(x -> System.out.print(x + "  "))
        .toArray();
}
```

Test

```java
addNextFour(2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 11, 0, 13, 8, 9, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6);
addNextFourStream(2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 11, 0, 13, 8, 9, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6);
```

Output

```
16  20  25  27  28  27  32  23  32  32  30  31  25  22  15  20  15  15  14  15  
16  20  25  27  28  27  32  23  32  32  30  31  25  22  15  20  15  15  14  15
```

Comment: thank you, your return void code fits my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Access your array using index modulo array length. This means any lookup extending out of the array circles back to the beginning.

`a[i] = a[(i + 1)%a.length] + a[(i + 2)%a.length] + a[(i + 3)%a.length] + a[(i + 4)%a.length];`

e.g array length =20

When looking up `a[17], a[18], a[19], a[20]`

`a[20]` does not exist

So look up `a[20%20]`, which is `a[0]`

The other lookups work as normal

`a[17%20]` looks up `a[17]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, are you saying something like this? (edited post)

Adding specific modulus can hold new values i.e a[21] = index 1, a[22] = index 2?

Comment: @HarryIguana Do not change your question like this otherwise you make the answer from user1717259 seem outdated

Comment: You only need the `a[i] = a[(i + 1)%a.length] + a[(i + 2)%a.length] + a[(i + 3)%a.length] + a[(i + 4)%a.length];` line. You don't need the if statement.

Comment: @dreamcrash sorry about that.

Comment: @user1717259 the last 4 numbers are printed incorrectly. It should be 15, 15, 14, 15.
int[] a = {2, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 9, 4, 8, 11, 0, 13, 8, 9, 1, 7, 5, 2, 6};
so for a[17] = 5+2+6+2 and so forth

Comment: @HarryIguana No problem, you are new to the side it is normal to do this mistakes